# What is the difference between static and dynamic binding?

Tags: programming-languages, language-design

Binding times can be classified between two types: static and dynamic.  What is the difference between static and dynamic binding?

Could you give a quick example of each to further illustrate it?

Comment: If it's homework, you'll be better off asking for a critique of your planned response; not for the answer outright.

Comment: @Daniel L, I marked it as homework.  This isn't directly the question in my homework.  I have to classify a bunch of things as static or dynamic and I'm trying to clear up in my head which is which through this question.  If people want to answer they will.

Comment: @KingNestor: Yes, I saw that it was homework ;]  I see what you mean now.

Answer (score 29):

In the most general terms, **static binding** means that references are resolved *at compile time*.

```
Animal a = new Animal();
a.Roar(); // The compiler can resolve this method call statically.
```

**Dynamic binding** means that references are resolved *at run time*.

```
public void MakeSomeNoise(object a) {
   // Things happen...
   ((Animal) a).Roar(); // You won't know if this works until runtime!
}
```

Comment: Not true, if object a = new Animal();

Comment: True, although I think it was obvious I was trying to be general. I adjusted it a bit.

Comment: Your latter example is still static binding.  The typecast may or may not succeed, but if the typecast succeeds, even if `Roar` is a virtual method, the code will be bound to the vtable slot statically associated with `Animal.Roar()`.  Dynamic binding only occurs in C# when either using the new `dynamic` type, or else by using Reflection (e.g. `a.GetType().GetMethod("Roar").Invoke(a, null)`).  The latter would work with any type that implements a parameterless method called `Roar`, and return the most derived implementation (even if a base implementation is non-virtual).

Comment: @supercat java has reflection too, from back in 1999 when .net was not even an idea! see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940844/getmethods-java

Comment: @supercat you're wrong. Languages like C++, Java and C# sure use dynamic binding when invoking virtual functions/methods. Vtables provide safety and shorten the lookup, but the right method is still effectively selected at runtime. The type of lookup used with C# `dynamic`, reflection and dynamic languages in general is sometimes called _late binding_, though _late_ and _dynamic_ are often used interchangeably, and the distinction isn't clear. Either way, John Feminella's second example is definitively _dynamic_, and not _static_, binding.

Comment: @eran: Binding occurs before dispatch, and among other things establishes the parameter signature and return type of the function to be called.  In the second example, the compiler can't know in advance whether the cast will succeed, but it can know in advance that if the method call is reached it will invoke a method that returns whatever `Animal.Roar` is declared as returning.

Comment: @supercat, let's ignore the cast for now, it's confusing for no good reason. Dynamic binding means the method to be invoked is determined at runtime, according to the dynamic type (which is the referenced object). Static typing (used by C++, Java etc., in which variables have types) makes dynamic dispatch faster and safer, but that's still considered dynamic binding. You can check out the C++ standard, which explicitly uses the term.

Comment: @eran: Invoking `Roar` upon a variable of type `object` without the cast would be dynamic binding, because the compiler would have no way of knowing what parameters `Roar` would expect (even invoked as shown, it might expect an empty param-array) or what it might return (its return value, if any is ignored, but the calling conventions vary depending upon whether it returns a reference type, value type, or nothing).  Casting to `Animal` before the call tells the compiler that the method invocation style will be that of `Animal`'s best match for `Roar()` passing no parameters.

Comment: @supercat, you can't simply invoke `Roar` on an `object`, because C# is a statically-typed language. Given `Animal a` can reference a `Bear` and a `Lion`, the compiler can't determine the actual implementation of `Roar` that should be invoked. It merely determine roar's signature and setup the call via whatever vtable found at runtime. Dynamic binding is a well defined term, which is widely used in languages specs and academic literature. Assuming `Roar` is virtual, calling it _is dynamic binding_ (and on dynamically-typed languages such as python, every call is dynamic binding).

Comment: Hey folks, I notice this comment thread is getting pretty back and forth. Just to clarify my intentions, while this looks like C#/Java, I meant for it to be interpreted as generic source code for an OO language and not C#/Java specifically, since the question itself is not about any language in particular.

Comment: @eran: There is an accepted meaning of `dynamic binding` which indicates that it entails determining the *signature and return type* of the method to be called.  Casting to `Animal` instructs the compiler to select, at compile time, the most suitable `Roar` signature *within `Animal`*.  As an analogy, static binding/static dispatch is like accessing an ordinary variable, static binding/virtual dispatch is like accessing an element of a static or automatic array, and virtual binding is more like accessing memory received from `malloc`.  They're all different, but only the last is "dynamic".

Answer (score 6):

It depends when the binding happens: at compile time (static) or at runtime (dynamic). Static binding is used when you call a simple class method. When you start dealing with class hierarchies and virtual methods, compiler will start using so called [VTABLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_table)s. At that time the compiler doesn't know exactly what method to call and it has to wait until runtime to figure out the right method to be invoked (this is done through [VTABLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_table)). This is called dynamic binding.

See Wikipedia article on [Virtual tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_table) for more details and references.

Answer (score 5):

I came accross this perfect answer of a quora user "Monis Yousuf". He explain this perfectly. I am putting it here for others.

Binding is mostly a concept in object oriented programming related to Polymorphism.

Firstly, understand what **Polymorphism** is. Books say that it means "one name and multiple forms". True, but too abstract. Let us take a real-life example. You go to a "Doctor", a doctor may be an eye-specialist, ENT specialist, Neuro-Surgeon, Homeopath etc.

Here, a "doctor" is a name and may have multiple types; each performing their own function. This is polymorphism in real life.

**Function Overloading:** This concept depicts Static Binding. Function overloading may be roughly defined as, two or more methods (functions) which have the same name but different signatures (including number of parameters, types of parameters, differt return types) are called overloaded methods (or functions).

Suppose you have to calculate area of a rectangle and circle. See below code:-

```
class CalculateArea {

    private static final double PI = 3.14;

    /* 
       Method to return area of a rectangle 
       Area of rectangle = length X width
    */
    double Area(double length, double width) {
        return (length * width);
    }

    /*
      Method to return area of circle
      Area of circle = π * r * r
    */
    double Area(double radius) {
        return PI * radius * radius;
    }
}
```

In above code, there are two methods "Area" with different parameters. This scenario qualifies as function overloading.

Now, coming to the real question: How is this static binding?

When you call any of the above functions in your code, you have to specify the parameters you are passing. In this scenario, you will pass either:

- Two parameters of type double [Which will call the first method, to
  calculate are of a rectangle]
- Single parameter of type double [Which will call the second method, to calculate area of a circle]

Since, at compile time the java compiler can figure out, WHICH function to call, it is compile-time (or STATIC) binding.

Function Overriding: Function overriding is a concept which is shown in inheritance. It may roughly be defined as: when there is a method present in a parent class and its subclass also has the same method with SAME signature, it is called function overriding. [There is more to it, but for the sake of simplicity, i have written this definition] It will be easier to understand with below piece of code.

```
class ParentClass {
    int show() {
        System.out.println("I am from parent class");
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass{
    int show() {
        System.out.println("I am from child class");
    }
}

class SomeOtherClass {
    public static void main (String[] s) {
        ParentClass obj = new ChildClass();
        obj.show();
    }
}
```

In above code, the method `show()` is being overridden as the same signature (and name) is present in both parent and child classes.

In the third class, `SomeOtherClass`, A reference variable (obj) of type `ParentClass` holds the object of ChildClass. Next, the method `show(`) is called from the same reference variable (obj).

Again, the same question: How is this Dynamic Binding?

At compile time, the compiler checks that the Reference variable is of type `ParentClass` and checks if the method `show()` is present in this class. Once it checks this, the compilation is successful.

Now, when the programs RUNS, it sees that the object is of `ChildClass` and hence, it runs the `show()` method of the `ChildClass`. Since this decision is taken place at RUNTIME, it is called **Dynamic Binding** (or Run-time Polymorphism).

[Link](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-static-and-dynamic-binding) for original answer

Answer (score 0):

**Static Binding:** is the process of resolving types, members and operations ***at compile-time.***
For example:

```
Car car = new Car();
car.Drive();
```

In this example compiler does the binding by looking for a parameterless `Drive` method on `car` object. If did not find that method! search for methods taking [optional parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments), and if did not found that method again search [base class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/inheritance) of `Car` for that method, and if did not found that method again searches for [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) for `Car` type. If no match found you'll get the compilation error!

I this case the *binding is done by the compiler*, and the binding depends on statically knowing the type of object. This makes it static binding.

**Dynamic Binding:** dynamic binding defers binding (The process of resolving types, members and operations) from compile-time to **runtime**.
For example:

```
dynamic d = new Car();
d.Drive();
```

A *dynamic type* tells the compiler we expect the *runtime type* of `d` to have `Drive` method, but we can't prove it *statically*. Since the `d` is dynamic, compiler defers binding `Drive` to d *until runtime*.

Dynamic binding is useful for cases that at compile-time we know that a certain function, member of operation exists but the compiler didn't know! This commonly occurs when we are interoperating with *dynamic programming languages*, *COM* and *reflection*.

Answer (score -4):

Binding done at compile time is static binding and binding done at run time is dynamic binding.In static binding data type of the pointer resolves which method is invoked.But in dynamic binding data type of the object resolves which method is invoked.

Answer (score -5):

*** Execution time:-*** bindings of variables to its values,as well as the binding of variable to particular storage location at the time of execution is called execution time binding.

IT MAY BE OF TWO TYPES

1. on entry to a subprogram.
2. At arbitrary points during execution time.

**COMPILE TIME BINDING :-**  (TRANSLATION TIME)
It consist of the following.

1. Binding chosen by programmer.
2. Binding chosen by the translator.
3. Binding chosen by the loader.