# getMethods(), java

Tags: java, reflection

In java, the method 'Class.getMethods()' returns an array of all the methods in the reciever class and also its superclasses.
Is there such a method like Class.getMethods() which only give us the class's methods, without those which are inhereted from its superclasses?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[getDeclaredMethods()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods())